# Docker container cannot pull github repo , name resolution fails

Tags: centos, docker, ipv6

I am using docker version 1.7 on `centos-6`:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1
```

The problem is: when somehow the `/etc/resolv.conf` file contains nameservers with ipv6 addresses, then it cannot resolve or pull some repos from github.

when I change name servers to IPv4 addresses only , it works again.

Is there any permanent solution to this problem? Do upgrading the docker version will fix it?

Or is there any other root cause of this problem?

The network settings of docker inspect command:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "EndpointID": "db30701ee55cf8f6b8c9fe42c820434648ed6cca5ca863c60e098f9d4ad825a3",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.8",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:08",
    "NetworkID": "db3910e86d7f291d5586c23895a67a1140e638afcdbbf5a6b60e10c9bbb85762",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/4273c53a95b2",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
},
```

on the host , `ipv6` is fully configured and ping6 command works fine. but inside the container i see `ipv6` fields blank. Any reason why there is no ipv6 inside the container?

moreover :

```
curl -g 'http://[2400:fc00:854a:aaaa:700d:d110:e593:8d00]'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2400:fc00:854a:aaaa:700d:d110:e593:8d00: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Do you have IPv6 addressing/routing for the Internet at large?

Comment: Yes , ipv6 is enabled on the host and i can ping6 google. 

`[root@cmsbuild30 ~]# ping6 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(mil02s06-in-x04.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from mil02s06-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.3 ms
64 bytes from mil02s06-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from mil02s06-in-x04.1e100.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=15.8 ms
`

Comment: Do the affected Docker containers have an IPv6 address?

Comment: Question update with docker inspect info

Comment: So the obvious answer to the question before you modified  is that there is no IPv6 configured inside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting any IPv6 routing/working inside the containers because as we have seen it, there is no IPv6 addressing working inside them, but only at the host level.

As per the [IPv6 user guide - networking - IPv6 with Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/)

> By default, the Docker server configures the container network for
>   IPv4 only. You can enable IPv4/IPv6 dualstack support by running the
>   Docker daemon with the --ipv6 flag. Docker will set up the bridge
>   docker0 with the IPv6 link-local address fe80::1.
>
> By default, containers that are created will only get a link-local
>   IPv6 address. To assign globally routable IPv6 addresses to your
>   containers you have to specify an IPv6 subnet to pick the addresses
>   from. Set the IPv6 subnet via the --fixed-cidr-v6 parameter when
>   starting Docker daemon:
>
> dockerd --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6="2001:db8:1::/64"
>
> The subnet for Docker
>   containers should at least have a size of /80. This way an IPv6
>   address can end with the container’s MAC address and you prevent NDP
>   neighbor cache invalidation issues in the Docker layer.
>
> With the --fixed-cidr-v6 parameter set Docker will add a new route to
>   the routing table. Further IPv6 routing will be enabled